# Hadoop MapReduce: Clarification on number of reducers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

In the MapReduce framework, one reducer is used for each key generated by the mapper.

So you would think that specifying the number of Reducers in Hadoop MapReduce wouldn't make any sense because it's dependent on the program.  However, Hadoop allows you to specify the number of reducers to use (-D mapred.reduce.tasks=# of reducers).

What does this mean?  Is the parameter value for number of reducers specifying how many machine resources go to the reducers instead of the number of actual reducers used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> one reducer is used for each key generated by the mapper

This comment is not correct.  One call to the reduce() method is done for each key grouped by the grouping comparator.  A reducer (task) is a process that handles zero or more calls to reduce().  The property to which you refer is talking about the number of reducer *tasks*.

Comment: this answer is very helpfiul

Answer (score 4):

To simplify @Judge Mental's (very accurate) answer a little bit: A reducer task can work on many keys at a time, but the mapred.reduce.tasks=# parameter declares how many simultaneous reducer tasks will run for a specific job.

An example if your mapred.reduce.tasks=10:
You have 2,000 keys, each key with 50 values (for an evenly distributed 10,000 k:v pairs).
Each reducer should be roughly handling 200 keys (1,000 k:v pairs).

An example if your mapred.reduce.tasks=20:
You have 2,000 keys, each key with 50 values (for an evenly distributed 10,000 k:v pairs).
Each reducer should be roughly handling 100 keys (500 k:v pairs).

In the example above, the fewer keys each reducer has to work with, the faster the overall job will be ... so long as you have the available reducer resources in the cluster, of course.

Comment: What if my mapper only outputs 1 key?  Will the number of reducers not matter since there are too few keys to split up the work among reducers?

Comment: That's known as data skew, and it can be a problem, depending on your data size.  The most common method of resolving or mitigating data skew is to create a custom Partitioner. This allows the data to be distributed the reducers in a different fashion.  There's a decent description on the Yahoo Hadoop Tutorial site on Partitioning Data:

http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#partitioning